# Serverless offline - middleware must contain at least one key among "before", "after", "OnError"

Tags: javascript, lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

Has anyone any idea of this kind of problem :
Middleware must contain at least one key among "before", "after", "onError" - at serverless offline (node js) when trying to include a middleware in the handler of any function. In this case : I have created a lambda function and a middy middleware (verifyToken), and I want that middleware to put it on my handler of the lambda function, but it keeps showing me the message I mention before; even though my middleware already have those keywords.
Here is my middleware:

```
export const verifyToken = async function verifyToken(event, context) {
  return {
    before: async ({ event }, next) => {
      const headers = JSON.parse(event.headers);
      const bearerHeader = headers.authorization;
      if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
        const token = bearer[1];

        const verify = util.promisify(jwt.verify);

        const data = await verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        event.user = data.user;
      } else {
        throw new Error("");
      }
    },
    onError: () => {
      return {
        statusCode: 401,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: "No Token Present",
        }),
      };
    },
  };
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware wrapper cannot be a promise. You can also remove the `onError` step and use the `handler.callback` to short circuit the call stack.

```js
// middy 1.x
const verifyToken = () => {
  return {
    before: (handler, next) => {
      // ... logic
      } else {
        // Triggers middy to exit early
        return handler.callback(null,  {
          statusCode: 401,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            message: "No Token Present",
          }),
        })
      }

      next()
    }
  }
}
```